# Applications of $p_{n+2}+p_{n+1} \le p_1p_2...p_n , \forall n >2$?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime number ; I know that $p_{n+2}+p_{n+1} \le p_1p_2...p_n , \forall n >2$ . I am looking for some applications of it , for example I know one application of it stating that if $q_n$ is the smallest prime not dividing $n$ then $q_n / n$ converges to $0$ . I am looking for some other applications . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you be looking for applications of such a weird inequality?

Comment: Equality cannot occur, right ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, it cannot occur.

Comment: @wythagoras: why equality cannot occur ?

Comment: When $n=3$, we get 30 and 18. When $n \geq 4$, Bertrand's postulate gives us $2p_n \geq p_{n+1}$ and  $4p_n \geq 2p_{n+1} \geq p_{n+2}$, and then use that the product of the first $n-1$ primes is bigger than 6 as $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 4):

The right hand side of your inequality grows much much faster than the left hand side, and therefore it cannot be used to prove any sharp results about the primes. It's kind of similar to the inequality $(n+1)+(n+2) \leq 1\cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$ : it's true for $n>3$ but almost trivially so. Below I show a plot of $f(n) = \frac{p_1p_2\ldots p_n}{p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}}$ for $1\leq n \leq 50$. Already at  $n=50$ we have $f(n) \simeq 10^{88}$ and for $n=100$ we have $f(n) \simeq  10^{216}$.

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

However, one potential application of your inequality is to obtain a (very weak) bound for the product $Q_n = p_1p_2\ldots p_n$. Multiplying your inequality by $Q_n$ we get

$$Q_n^2 \geq \frac{Q_{n+2}}{p_{n+1}} + Q_{n+1} > Q_{n+1} \implies Q_{n+1} < Q_n^{2^1} < Q_{n-1}^{2^2} < \ldots < Q_1^{2^{n}} = 2^{2^{n}}$$

so $p_1p_2\ldots p_n < 2^{2^{n}}$.

Comment: we also have $\dfrac{Q_{n+2}}{p_{n+1}}\gt Q_{n+1}$, so we can tighten the upper bound a bit.